# × TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'salaryanswer' of 'steps' as it is undefined. reactjs

Tags: reactjs, chatbot

The following error occurs while running the project.

**This is the error:**

[image: This is the error]

code ->

```
 class Chatgraph extends Component {

       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       const { steps } = this.props;
       const {  salaryanswer, rate } = steps;   
       this.setState({salaryanswer,rate });
       }
```

I am developing a chatbot.

in chatbot,
A graph should be generated by taking the user's salary and salary increment rate.
chatbot code ->

```
// User answer
        {
          id: "salaryanswer",
          user: true,

          delay: 1300,
          validator: (value) => {
            if (isNaN(value)) {
              return 'Salary should be a number';
            }
            if (isNaN(value) || value < 1000) {
              return "Salary must be above Rs 1000 ";
            }
            return true;
          },
          trigger: "salary-user-answer-one",
        },
```

Comment: Then `steps` is `undefined`.  What information do you have which indicates otherwise?

Comment: steps being undefined means that it has not been set.

if you try to take something out of nothing, it is impossible. 

what you can do, is give it a "default" value. so it can be defined without the "props" being set.

Comment: I am developing a chatbot.
in chatbot
A graph should be generated by taking the user's salary and salary increment rate.   I have updated my questions, please check  it

Comment: reference: https://www.ordinarycoders.com/blog/article/reactjs-chatbot

Answer (score 0):

steps being undefined means that it has not been set. if you try to take something out of nothing, it is impossible. what you can do, is give it a "default" value. so it can be defined without the "props" being set.